# How to properly enter values into a matrix?

Tags: c

I want to enter values into a matrix, but the code that I use for some reason "skips" values. To enter values in a matrix of 3 X 3 (9 values) I need to type 10.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int matrix[3][3];
int i,j /*indexes for loops*/
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    printf("Enter value for position [%d][%d]: ", i,j);
    scanf("%d ",&matrix[i][j]);
  }
}
```

This is what I got from the terminal:

```
Enter a value for position [0][0]: 0
1
Enter a value for position [0][1]: 0
Enter a value for position [0][2]: 0
Enter a value for position [1][0]: 0
Enter a value for position [1][1]: 0
Enter a value for position [1][2]: 1
Enter a value for position [2][0]: 0
Enter a value for position [2][1]: 0
Enter a value for position [2][2]: 0
```

The Matrix DOES print as following:

```
0  1  0
0  0  0  
1  0  0
```

but I am stuck with a 0 for my next calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space in the format string tells scanf() to match zero or more whitespace characters, until the match fails. Spaces (' '), newlines('\n'), carriage returns ('\r'), and tabs ('\t') are among the whitespace characters. When a space occurs at the end of a format string, scanf() will try to match whitespace characters from the input until no match is found. But, scanf() can only return when a match fails, or end of file is reached,thus,space after %d in **scanf("%d ",&matrix[i][j])**  is the cause of this error.
Remove the space and it will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

You have a space in your `scanf`. Removing it fixes the problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int matrix[3][3];
int i,j /*indexes for loops*/
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    printf("Enter value for position [%d][%d]: ", i,j);
    scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
  }
}
```